# Neural Network in Tensorflow give 0 Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

the input does not have any NaN value, but the accuracy is always 0.

```
    n_nodes_hl1 = 3000
    n_nodes_hl2 = 1500
    n_nodes_hl3 = 1000

    n_classes   = 3
    batch_size  = 5
    hm_epochs   = 5 

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction=neural_network_model(x)
    cost=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = prediction, labels = y)
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            #while i < len(train_x):
            t = len(train_x)
            f = t%batch_size
            while i < (t-f):
                start = i
                end = i+batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                #epoch_loss = epoch_loss + c
                i+=batch_size
                #i = i + batch_size
            print('Epoch =', epoch+1, '/',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

        save_path = saver.save(sess, "sesionestensorflow/model1802.ckpt")
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))
```

i understand that it could be the loss function and if it is the case, the neural network need a clip by value procedure.

Comment: please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I tried your code, filling in the blanks with a small mnist model model and I get an accuracy of 0.89

Comment: please share `neural_network_model` function

Comment: yes, it works with mnist data but .
('Epoch =', 4, '/', 5, 'loss:', array([9.8745392e+07, 1.0229302e+08, 1.4922563e+08, 1.0039674e+08,
       1.0269134e+08], dtype=float32))
('Epoch =', 5, '/', 5, 'loss:', array([6.23470680e+07, 1.58039536e+08, 1.00448512e+08, 9.89495440e+07,
       1.16965416e+08], dtype=float32))
Model saved in path: sesionestensorflow/model1802.ckpt
('Accuracy:', 0.0)

Comment: the model is.(def neural_network_model(data):

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['bias'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['bias']

    return output)

Comment: I use relu6 instead of relu in the model and the accuracy is the same, equal to 0